# Conditional alert in kibana watcher

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elasticsearch-watcher, hermes-jms

Is it possible to set the alert condition like ..the alert should trigger after 10 mins  after it reaches the threshold value..

Note : we have to wait for 10 mins after it reaches the threshold value .. Just wants to know whether the value is getting drained or not ..if it's not then alert should trigger.

Thanks,
Velu G

Comment: Could you share some more details about the data. How do we calculate threshold value. Sample mapping and data if you can update in the question, would be useful for us to help you.

Comment: Hi ,                                                                             For example my threshold value for cpu usage is 70%.Now my condition is if cpu went to 70% also i don't want the alert to be trigger immediately....will wait for 10 mins to check whether the cpu is getting drain or not ...if value is not getting drain.. then the alert should trigger . Please let me know if you need any more information on this.